# Create a dynamic list of tables used by all the dashboards on the server

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

Is it possible to create something which extracts all the database/table names being used by multiple dashboards? We have a lot of old and new dashboards and we wanted to extract which tables are being used by the dashboards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give this a try

https://help.qlik.com/en-US/governance-dashboard/Content/QV_GovDashboard/What.htm

It has a data lineage tab that can show you some stuff and I imagine help you to build your own custom solution

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure that this is possible. Or at least not easy to achieve. In order to extract such info:

- loop through all apps and extract the script
- parse the Qlik script and find/extract all sql statements
- parse these statements and extract the database/tables

Extracting the scripts is the easiest part here.

Isolating the sql statements might be doable but then parsing the sql will have to be done by something.

There is no complete Qlik script parser so potentially using string manipulations to extract the sql statements (imo depends on the sql complexity). (I havent lost hope to complete [qlik-script-parser](https://github.com/countnazgul/qlik-script-parser) but have to spend a lot of time on it in order to complete it)

There are tools (like [sqlformat](https://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm) chose output to be `List DB Object`) that can extract tables and fields but not sure if automation can be achieved.